# extracting the actual output of generator in a list

Tags: python, generator, spacy, yield-from

I am trying to get the actual output from the generator but i get the ouput as generator object. Please help me achieve the actual output from the generator

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def lemmatizer(words):
     yield from [w.lemma_ for w in nlp(words)]

list1 = ['birds hanging on street','people playing cards']

a = list(map(lemmatizer,list1))
```

Output:

```
a
[<generator object....>,
<generator object....>]
```

Expected output:

```
a
['birds hang on street',
'people play card']
```

Comment: `a = list(map(list, map(lemmatizer,list1)))`

Comment: @PatrickArtner please write the answer, now i get the output as list within list of tokens, pls join the inner list as each sentence, thanks.. should i change the lemmatizer function a bit for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me with the help of @PatrickArtner comment

```
a = list(map(list, map(lemmatizer,list1)))
b = list(map(' '.join, a))
```

Comment: You can self accept in about 28h or so :) glad it helped

Answer (score -1):

Use `next` to yield from the generator. Adding `next` like `a = list(next(map(lemmatizer,list1)))` should work.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')

def lemmatizer(words):
     yield from [w.lemma_ for w in nlp(words)]

list1 = ['birds hanging on street','people playing cards']

a = list(next(map(lemmatizer,list1)))
```

Comment: next() only retrieves one thing from the generator though?